# Append menu item in another process using DLL injection

Tags: delphi, dll, code-injection

I want to inject a dll into another process in order to insert an item into the main menu of that process and handle the click event.

This is the DLL file:

```
library test;

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  Winapi.Messages,
  System.Classes,
  System.Generics.Collections;

{$R *.res}


var
  LSysMenu : HMenu;
  OldWndProc: TFarProc;

function NewWndProc(hWnd: HWND; Msg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): Longint; stdcall;
begin
case WM_COMMAND of
      2000:
      MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP, 'You pressed our new menu button!', 'Yay!', MB_OK);
      end;
Result := CallWindowProc(OldWndProc, hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
end;

var
HwndWind:HWND;
begin
    HwndWind :=  FindWindow(nil,PChar('Test App'));
    if HwndWind <> 0 then
    Begin
        LSysMenu := GetMenu(HwndWind);
        LSysMenu := GetSubMenu(LSysMenu, 3);
        //hNewMenu := CreateMenu();
        AppendMenu(LSysMenu, MF_STRING,2000, 'test');
        //AppendMenu(hNewMenu, MF_STRING, 2000, 'Button');
        DrawMenuBar(HwndWind);
        OldWndProc := SetWindowLong(HwndWind, GWL_WNDPROC,LONG(@NewWndProc));
    End;

end.
```

The target process crashes unless I comment out the line

```
//OldWndProc := SetWindowLong(HwndWind, GWL_WNDPROC,LONG(@NewWndProc));
```

in which case the new item will be added to the menu, but its handler will not be called.

What is wrong with my `NewWndProc` function or the parameters to the `SetWindowLong` function?

I have based my code on [this C++ code](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/17456-window-subclassing-with-dll-injection/).

Comment: Try `var OldWndProc: TFarProc;`, then `OldWndPRoc := SetWindowLong(...`, then `CallWindowProc(OldWndProc,...`. That's how they do it in Forms.pas.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError thanks i change it from Long to TFarProc but i get the below error (in David answer)

Comment: Your edit means that the code no longer compiles!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Result := CallWindowProc(@OldWndProc, hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
```

Here you are passing the address of the variable that holds the address of the window procedure. That's one level of indirection too far. Instead write:

```
Result := CallWindowProc(OldWndProc, hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
```

When you get the window proc to run, it won't work. Your case statement is all wrong. Please read the documentation carefully. You need to test `Msg` against `WM_COMMAND`, and the low word of `wParam` against your ID.

```
case Msg of
WM_COMMAND:
  case LoWord(wParam) of
  2000:
    ....
  end;
end;
```

**Update** Your edit changes the code so that it no longer compiles. The type mis-match error can be fixed with a cast:

```
OldWndProc := TFarProc(SetWindowLong(...));
```

It is a little frustrating that you change multiple things and once. Solving these problems is hard enough without having to take aim at a moving target.

Comment: in this line `OldWndProc := SetWindowLong(HwndWind, GWL_WNDPROC,LONG(@NewWndProc));` i get `E2010 Incompatible types: Pointer and NativeInt`

Comment: That is the code that is in the question. Code that you claim that compiles. So I guess you changed some code. Now you can see that change and I cannot. It's going to be difficult for me to comment on code that only you can see. What's more, even in the question, you don't say what `OldWndProc` is. My guess is that you need to cast the return value of `SetWindowLong`. I guess that `OldWndProc` is of type `Pointer`. In which case just cast the return value of `SetWindowLong` to `Pointer`. Or whatever alias to `Pointer` that you used when declaring `OldWndProc`.

Comment: `TFarProc(SetWindowLong(...));` thanks the compiles issue solved but still the handler not be called (the click event).

Comment: You asked about the crash.

Comment: I can answer that too though. Just give me a minute.